# Why does my List of Objects rendered as Checkboxes return an Empty List? [ASP.NET Core - 3.1]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to render a `List<PlayerCheckbox>` as Checkboxes.

PlayerCheckbox looks like this:
(added empty constructor as per @jcwmoore 's answer, sadly nothing changed with this addition alone)

```cs
 public class PlayerCheckbox
    {
        public PlayerCheckbox(string discordName, ulong discordId, bool selected = false)
        {
            DiscordName = discordName;
            DiscordId = discordId;
            Selected = selected;
        }

        public PlayerCheckbox()
        {

        }

        public string DiscordName { get; set; }

        public ulong DiscordId { get; set; }

        public bool Selected { get; set; }
    }
```

The CreateBingoTaskModel looks like this: (ViewModel I am working with on the Create page, added a default constructor here aswell per @jcwmoore 's input, just in case)

```cs
 public class CreateBingoTaskModel
    {
        public CreateBingoTaskModel()
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Discord Id of the creator of this BingoTask
        /// </summary>
        public BingoPlayer Creator { get; set; }

        [Range(0, 100)]
        public int Difficulty { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// List of IDs that are not allowed to receive this bingo task
        /// </summary>
        public List<BingoPlayer> BlackListIds { get; set; } = new List<BingoPlayer>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Title of this bingo task
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        public string BingoTitle { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Description of this bingo task
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        public string BingoDescription { get; set; }

        public DateTime RaffledOn { get; set; }

        public List<PlayerCheckbox> BlackList;
    }
```

The setup GET-Create looks like this:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
        {
            CreateBingoTaskModel createBingoModel = new CreateBingoTaskModel();
            createBingoModel.BlackList = new List<PlayerCheckbox>();

            var user = await appDb.BingoPlayers.SingleOrDefaultAsync(player =>
                player.LoginName == HttpContext.Session.GetString("user"));

            foreach (BingoPlayer bp in appDb.BingoPlayers)
            {
                PlayerCheckbox playerCheckbox =
                    new PlayerCheckbox(bp.Name, bp.DiscordId);
                if (playerCheckbox.DiscordId != user.DiscordId)
                {
                    createBingoModel.BlackList.Add(playerCheckbox);
                }
            }

            return View(createBingoModel);
        }
```

The POST-Create looks like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateBingoTaskModel createBingoTaskModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await appDb.BingoPlayers.SingleOrDefaultAsync(player =>
                    player.LoginName == HttpContext.Session.GetString("user"));

                foreach (PlayerCheckbox checkbox in createBingoTaskModel.BlackList)
                {
                    if (checkbox.Selected)
                    {
                        var player = appDb.BingoPlayers.Single(bingoPlayer => bingoPlayer.DiscordId == checkbox.DiscordId);
                        createBingoTaskModel.BlackListIds.Add(player);
                    }
                }

                createBingoTaskModel.BlackListIds.Add(user);

                BingoTask newBingoTask = new BingoTask
                {
                    Difficulty = createBingoTaskModel.Difficulty,
                    BingoTitle = createBingoTaskModel.BingoTitle,
                    BingoDescription = createBingoTaskModel.BingoDescription,
                    BlackListIds = createBingoTaskModel.BlackListIds
                };

                appDb.Add(newBingoTask);
                await appDb.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(createBingoTaskModel);
        }
```

Looking at the Model in the POST-Create Header:
[image: PostCreate Model Screenshot] shows that the BlackList is *now null*.

> I Do not understand why this is null, I was expecting all of the players except for the current logged in user, even if the logic was incorrect, `.BlackList` should at least be initialized.

The Checkbox List Code I am using looks like this:

```cs
@using App.API.Models
@model App.API.Models.CreateBingoTaskModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>BingoTask</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Difficulty" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Difficulty" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Difficulty" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BingoTitle" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="BingoTitle" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="BingoTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BingoDescription" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="BingoDescription" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="BingoDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <span>BlackList</span>

               @for (int i = 0; i < Model.BlackList.Count; i++)
                {
                    <input hidden asp-for="BlackList[i].DiscordId" />
                    <input hidden asp-for="BlackList[i].DiscordName" />
                    <input asp-for="BlackList[i].Selected" type="checkbox" />
                    @Model.BlackList[i].DiscordName
                    <br />
                }
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

and is taken from this answer here:
https://forums.asp.net/t/2164304.aspx?Asp+net+MVC+Core+giving+null+checkbox+data+instead+of+all+selected+checkboxes+on+HTTPPost

Many implementations of CheckboxLists have extremely similar frontend code with the only major change being a replacement of for with foreach(playerCheckbox in BlackList) which I have tried too.

My FormData looks... fine? (Except the extra values at the bottom)
[image]

I do NOT understand at all why the binding doesn't work here. Am I so tired that I am overlooking somethingy extremely simple?

If more information / code is needed, I will gladly provide more context where needed.

Comment: Have you verified (by stepping through it), that your Create method is actually called? No point even questioning the rendering logic if the value is null or the list is empty

Comment: question about model binding should be simple like this: post your action method that handles the post request, post the view code (including info about its model). That's all. Here I don't see your action method that handles to post request.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Yes, I can confirm both Get & Post Creates are being hit.

Comment: @KingKing I will add the Post Create Method Code too tomorrow if you want to see it, although I don't understand why that's important to you when I've posted a Screenshot from the Model it receives when Post Create is hit.

Comment: mainly @beggarboy because we need to confirm that your code is working as expected, in a local project these issues are very easy to step through to isolate the point in time that the data does not match the expectation, but here we have to assume that eveything else is correct, something is clearly NOT correct, so you should include as much information as you have access to.

Comment: `asp-for="@Model.BlackList` => `asp-for="BlackList` (shouldn't matter though). But we need to see how your post method is defined and what http values are being posted, your get method isn't relevant at all.

Comment: @KingKing I have added the information you asked for. Apologies if anything from myself yesterday came across as rude, it was like 3am. If you need any more code, info, or context, please let me know and I will gladly provide it all.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I added more code I was asked for, please see the parent comment above.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I added more code I was asked for, please see the parent comment above.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I beautified that part of the frontend, no change sadly in functionality.

Comment: I think you should focus on the `.BlackList = null` in the view `Create` response, that should definitely have a value. In my short repo it does, so I'm not sure what else is at fault here. The rest looks good enough

Comment: @beggarboy actually you just need to post the action method signature (because the code inside does not matter). I generally require that to know what's wrong first, the question is fairly long so we are not always interested in it. Here I see everything looks OK now ***except*** this `public List<PlayerCheckbox> BlackList;` which is strange at first. Actually looks like public fields are not bound, you need to declare ***public property***. We always use public properties so at the first sight seeing that, it's really strange and it turned out that's your issue.

Comment: @KingKing Oh my God. It was the lacking property definition with get-set; I knew it had to be something painfully simple but I couldn't put my finger on it. I guess at 3am I was too code blind to see something so obvious. (I now remember not seeing any VS references to the property and thinking that that was kinda odd, but didnt look further into it) It's all working perfect now. I would like to give you the answer on this since you sniped the issue. I removed jcwmoores addition and that would have been the next error I would stumble into, but ASP.NET throws an error about this in that case.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Because you're not a muppet like me and definitely made that List a public property. KingKing saw this an hour ago. It's all working fine now. I seriously thought there was an issue with CheckboxLists in AspNetCore3.1 for a hot second. Thank you all kindly guys for finding this so fast! ❤

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the model binder requires a default (parameterless) constructor in the model class.  The model class is fine, but the PlayerCheckbox does not have a parameterless constructor. Try either removing your constructor, or adding a parameterless one, to the PlayerCheckbox class.

```
public class PlayerCheckbox
{
    // default parameterless constructor to support deserialization
    public PlayerCheckbox()
    {

    }

    public PlayerCheckbox(string discordName, ulong discordId, bool selected = false)
    {
        DiscordName = discordName;
        DiscordId = discordId;
        Selected = selected;
    }

    public string DiscordName { get; set; }

    public ulong DiscordId { get; set; }

    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is certainly part of the overall issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried adding a default constructor to PlayerCheckbox, that didn't change anything sadly. I also added a empty default constructor to CreateBingoTaskModel() just in case. This was a definite oversight on my part, thank you for pointing this out, even if this alone didn't resolve my issue!

Comment: @KingKing found the issue that was giving me heavy headaches yesterday, but after fixing the missing property this would have been the next immediate issue. I would like to give the answer to KingKing, since he found what was bugging me the most, but you have my upvote since you saved me from the follow-up error. Thank you kindly!